# Jmeter: format statistics data to have comma in HTML report

Tags: performance, jmeter, report, performance-testing, load-testing

Is there a way to transform the statistics data to have comma (,) instead of dot (.) in the generated HTML report.

Like for the data in the attached image.

[image: Statistics data from Jmeter]

Comment: You should be able to customize the HTML reports through files in the `JMETER_HOME/bin/report-template` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something you can [customize via JMeter Properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization), you will have to do some [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/) programming (not very complex thought)

1. Locate `dashboard.js.fmkr` file under `report-template\content\js` folder (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)
2. You will need to change 2 lines, as of JMeter 5.4.1 they are:

   - [Line # 194](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/bin/report-template/content/js/dashboard.js.fmkr#L194) which looks like: `item = item.toFixed(2) + '%';`, you need to change it to:

     ```
     item = item.toFixed(2).toString().replace('.', ',') + '%';
     ```
   - [Line # 213](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/bin/report-template/content/js/dashboard.js.fmkr#L213) which looks like: `item = item.toFixed(2);`, similarly change it to:

     ```
     item = item.toFixed(2).toString().replace('.', ',')
     ```

[Regenerate the dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report) and you should see the commas instead of dots.

Comment: Awesome Dmitri, Its obvious you are a professional in this. Thumbs up !!!